# Is radiative decay the same the electromagnetic decay?

Tags: mesons, baryons

Question could be a duplicated of this one ["Radiative" particle decay?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/138339/radiative-particle-decay)

An electromagnetic decay should be clearly one that involves at least a photon, either directly or producing a pair particle/antiparticle. On other hand, I am tempted to think of "radiative" as the kind of decays related to transitions between excited states.

I am not sure if the decays mediated by gluons or by W and Z can not be called "radiative". Can they?

To clarify: I am asking about decays of mesons and baryons, and modern usage.

Answer (score 1):

Some names have historical reasons.

Long ago there were alpha rays and beta rays and gamma rays. All three were things that could be emitted during radioactive decay and they were grouped and ordered by how far they usually penetrate.

Only later did we learn that alpha rays were actually helium nuclei and that a beta ray was either an electron or a positron and that the gamma rays were just really high frequency light.

Now we understand all those processes in more detail. For instance, we know that a neutrino is also emitted during beta decay. And that a gamma ray can be emitted very shortly after the actual decay.

But originally they were all rays. So the process that produced them was radioactive.

At least that's the kind of history that goes into the average physics book. You could go back to Becquerel rays. But those aren't really about changes in atoms. But the word originally can mean different things to different people.

Things were called rays becsuse X rays were new rays that can go through opaque objects so all the newly found things that could do that were called rays.